# Identify video port on a Compaq mini

Tags: video, graphics-card, hdmi

[image: Compaq Mini 730]

Compaq Mini 730

In the photo you can see the video port, what is that port?

Is there a converter for that to HDMI? (Or a USB HDMI adapter or USB Video Card "cheap solution of course")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01794670) suggests its an expansion port which connects an optional VGA cable, which allows you to connect an external VGA monitor or
projector.

You'll need to find a [HP Mini VGA cable](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01794670) with that propitiatory port on one end and VGA on the other.